# Need feedback on my fictional map's coastline

Tags: internal-consistency, geography

Redoing an old map from scratch, want to get any problems with the coastline/placement/scaling of the land before I get to work on it. I am looking to make it as believable as possible.

Here is the current map with some notes added on: [image]

This is the old one for reference with a rough sketch of tectonic plate placement added on:[image]

Any feedback would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Updated map:[image]

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and visit our [help].  Stack Exchange [is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).  They are Q&A sites where specific questions receive specific answers.  Asking for general commentary is off-topic.  Do you have a specific question about your map that leads you to believe it might not be believable?

Comment: Like maybe about that funky outlet into the ocean, or the mountains on the plate east of it?

Comment: good map +1 for detail, can i ask what your using the map for (a book, game ect) just interested. also if you want send a message to some one just use the @ then there name like so @Netscapdov

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There should probably be an island chain extending north around the borders between plates 1, 2, and 3, perhaps a inlet around the border between 2 and 4, and a continuation of the western mountain range westward along the 3/4 border.

Other than that, maybe make the inland sea shallower except along plate borders, and maybe turn the eastern archipelago into a larger arc with some other islands to the NE (similar to the Greek Islands).

The coastline itself looks pretty good though.

Edit: But maybe shrink the size of the map (in km) by a factor of about 25%. 5800 km is a bit too large for a Mediterranean-esque sea

Comment: I think the distances would still be a bit too big to further extend the archipelago. That aside I agree with your other suggestions and will implement them in, thanks!

Comment: Thank! Also what sorta latitude is the region at? Essentially the same as Europe?

Comment: Something like that. Thought of it as the tip of the Southern peninsula being at a comparable latitude with Mauritania/Western Sahara.

Comment: Just to clarify this is referring to the peninsula at the very bottom of the map not the one on the Eastern landmass.

Comment: Small suggestion not worth its own answer: Between plates 2 and 4, just south of the mountain range, you have a divergent boundary on land, which should create a rift valley.

Comment: That was what I meant by the inlet. It would be a flooded rift valley.

Comment: Plate 2 would be quite a bit undersized now that I have shrunk the map. I could combine it and 4 to get a similar effect for the sea and just extend the mountain range further. This would also justify that mountain range being as large as I intended it to be with two immense tectonic plates colliding. If I did keep plate 2 then how big should the rift valley be and how should it look on a map?

Comment: Probably it should be a bit wider than the western mountain range with low mountains flanking an inlet that turns into a valley as one heads westward.  

But if 2 & 4 merge (which I think is more realistic actually) maybe put mountains on the west side of the northern strait similar to those on the east. Then have two parallel chains of long narrow islands going through the inland sea along the plate boundary (a flooded rift valley). Perhaps the inland sea was originally land millions of years ago when these features formed.

Comment: I'll go with the merger idea and keep this as my final map silhouette. I already had the Western area of the strait as an elevetaed, hilly, highland-esque area though not outright mountainous. I might still add some islands along the boundry though I feel like this would be overloading the map a bit.

Comment: I like overloading tho. Especially with islands and inland seas. (The only thing I like better than islands, or lakes, is islands *in* lakes.)

Answer (score -1):

The angle of the 2-4 boundary creates some issues to my way of thinking about tectonic movement. The area near the 1-4 boundary will be a subduction centre causing an Andes style mountain range, after the boundary turns the corner to trend north-west south-east it becomes a rifting zone, it's not impossible, just a bit odd looking, also the mountain range at the 2-3 boundary should continue along the 3-4 boundary as a transform fault range, similar to the Southern Alps and/or the Sierra Navada range.